# C++ critical section with timeout

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

**NOTE: My implementation is based on codeproject [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/CritSectEx.aspx) by Vladislav Gelfer.**

Based on [valdok](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=541463)'s codes, I rewrote the critical section class. The difference is that my implementation integrated recursive(reentrantable) locking feature into a single critical section class. (FYI, valdok provides 2 classes: one without recursion and the other with recursion.)

I just want to verify that my implementation is still correct and intact.

**Please, do not try to argue that the implementation is meaningless against using the WIN32 critical section object. I think this implementation has many advantages for many reasons. And, one reason is I needed to provide `try_enter()` feature for all versions of Windows.**

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#pragma intrinsic(_WriteBarrier)
#pragma intrinsic(_ReadWriteBarrier)

class critical_section
{
private:
    struct cpu_type
    {
        enum type
        {
            unknown,
            single,
            multiple
        };
    };

public:
    critical_section(u32 spin_count=0)
        : m_semaphore(null)
        , m_thread_id(0)
        , m_wait_count(0)
        , m_spin_count(0)
        , m_recur_count(0)
    {
        // determine the cpu type
        if( m_cpu_type == cpu_type::unknown )
        {
            SYSTEM_INFO sys_info;
            ::GetSystemInfo(&sys_info);         

            m_cpu_type = (sys_info.dwNumberOfProcessors > 1)?cpu_type::multiple:cpu_type::single;
        }

        // set the spin count.
        set_spin_count(spin_count);
    }

    ~critical_section()
    {
        if(m_semaphore != null)
        {
            CloseHandle(m_semaphore);
            m_semaphore = null;
        }

        ::memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));
    }

    void set_spin_count(u32 count)
    {
        // on single core, there should be no spinning at all.
        if(m_cpu_type == cpu_type::multiple)
        {
            m_spin_count = count;
        }
    }

public:
    bool enter(u32 timeout=INFINITE)
    {
        u32 cur_thread_id = ::GetCurrentThreadId();

        if(cur_thread_id == m_thread_id)
        {
            // already owned by the current thread.
            m_recur_count++;
        }
        else
        {
            if((!m_thread_id && lock_immediate(cur_thread_id))
                || (timeout && lock_internal(cur_thread_id, timeout)))
            {
                // successfully locked!
                m_recur_count = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // failed to lock!
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    bool try_enter()
    {
        return enter(0);
    }

    void leave()
    {
        assert(m_recur_count > 0);
        if(--m_recur_count == 0)
        {
            unlock_internal();
        }
    }

    inline bool is_acquired() const
    {
        return (::GetCurrentThreadId() == m_thread_id);
    }

private:
    inline bool lock_immediate(u32 thread_id)
    {
        // return true only if m_thread_id was 0 (and, at the same time, replaced by thread_id).
        return (_InterlockedCompareExchange(reinterpret_cast<long volatile*>(&m_thread_id), thread_id, 0) == 0);
    }

    bool lock_kernel(u32 thread_id, u32 timeout)
    {
        bool waiter = false;

        for(u32 ticks=GetTickCount();;)
        {
            if(!waiter) _InterlockedIncrement(reinterpret_cast<long volatile*>(&m_wait_count));

            // try locking once again before going to kernel-mode.
            if(lock_immediate(thread_id)) return true;

            u32 wait;
            if(timeout==INFINITE)
            {
                wait = INFINITE;
            }
            else
            {
                // update the remaining time-out.
                wait = GetTickCount()-ticks;
                if(timeout<=wait) return false; // timed-out
                wait = timeout-wait;
            }

            // go kernel
            assert(m_semaphore!=null);
            switch(WaitForSingleObject(m_semaphore, wait))
            {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                // got a change!
                waiter = false;
                break;
            case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                // timed-out.
                // but, there's one more change in the upper section of the loop.
                waiter = true;
                break;
            default:
                assert(false);
            }
        }
    }

    bool lock_internal(u32 thread_id, u32 timeout)
    {
        // try spinning and locking
        for(u32 spin=0; spin<m_spin_count; spin++)
        {
            if(lock_immediate(thread_id)) return true;

            // give chance to other waiting threads.
            // on single-core, it does nothing.
            YieldProcessor();
        }

        // prepare semaphore object for kernel-mode waiting.
        allocate_semaphore();

        bool locked = lock_kernel(thread_id, timeout);
        _InterlockedDecrement(reinterpret_cast<long volatile*>(&m_wait_count));

        return locked;
    }

    void unlock_internal()
    {
        // changes done to the shared resource are committed.
        _WriteBarrier();

        // reset owner thread id.
        m_thread_id = 0;

        // critical section is now released.
        _ReadWriteBarrier();

        // if there are waiting threads:
        if(m_wait_count > 0)
        {
            _InterlockedDecrement(reinterpret_cast<long volatile*>(&m_wait_count));

            // wake up one of them by incrementing semaphore count by 1.
            assert(m_semaphore);
            ReleaseSemaphore(m_semaphore, 1, null);
        }
    }

    void allocate_semaphore()
    {
        if(m_semaphore==null)
        {
            // create a semaphore object.
            HANDLE semaphore = CreateSemaphore(null, 0, 0x7FFFFFFF, null);
            assert(semaphore!=null);

            // try assign it to m_semaphore.
            if(InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(&m_semaphore, semaphore, null)!=null)
            {
                // other thread already created and assigned the semaphore.
                CloseHandle(semaphore);
            }
        }
    }

private:
    // prevent copying
    critical_section(const critical_section&);
    void operator=(const critical_section&);

private:
    // type of cpu: single-core or multiple-core
    static cpu_type::type m_cpu_type;

    // owner thread's id
    volatile u32 m_thread_id;
    // number of waiting threads
    volatile u32 m_wait_count;
    // spinning count
    volatile u32 m_spin_count;

    // recursion(reentrance) count
    s32 m_recur_count;

    // semaphore for kernel-mode wait
    volatile HANDLE m_semaphore;
};
```

Don't worry about a static member. `critical_section::m_cpu_type` is defined and initialized to `unknown` in other .cpp file.

Comment: It would be nice if you provided unit tests for this piece of code, because it's hard to test it's correctness based on only it's implementation. *Also, why not stick to something like `boost::threads` and don't spend your time reinventing the wheel?*

Comment: Even if he is reinventing the wheel, it could be because the existing wheel isn't round enough. I grow tired of that stupid argument. Let people write their code for pity's sake. Who knows, maybe we'll learn something from a radical new idea rather than stagnating with what we already have.

Comment: Thanks guys. As I stated, I just wanted to verify that my implementation is still intact. Actually, I'm using boost. Don't worry about it :)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `memset` in your code? Also, you are modifying `m_recur_count` concurrently without locking. **This is not an atomic variable**. The code *will* provoke a race condition. Also note that the `CRITICAL_SECTION` struct doesn’t even bother declaring its members as `volatile` since `volatile` does nothing here. In conclusion, no this implementation isn’t correct. I can’t verify whether valdok’s original code is since I have to register to CP to download the source code.

Answer (score 5):

To be honest it is quite difficult to verify this sort of thing works by dry running code.

I would take the original code and design some test cases which show it working.
Run them with and without the code.

Then design some test cases which fail due to the problem you have spotted, or perhaps do not work well enough without your enhancement.

Run those test cases over your new code (all of them not just the newest ones) and hey presto you know if your code works.

Comment: Writing unit tests which reliably show faults in parallel code is *hard*, almost as hard as writing those implementations in the first place. That’s not to say that you shouldn’t write tests, they are still great for showing failure. But you mustn’t rely on them. So I agree with this answer, except the last sentence.